# A file does not exist for module element having uri: EJB.jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb, websphere

I have recently installed IntelliJ on my machine and attempting to pull in a Module but am running into an error that looks like this:

> [5/2/16 9:41:08:079 EDT] 0000014e wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl openNestedArchive - module An error occurred while opening a nested archive: IWAE0006E Archive is not a valid EJB JAR File because the deployment descriptor can not be found (case sensitive): META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
>   IWAE0006E Archive is not a valid EJB JAR File because the deployment descriptor can not be found (case sensitive): META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
>
> [5/2/16 9:41:08:079 EDT] 0000014e wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl openNestedArchive(String) An error occurred while opening a nested archive: IWAE0023E Unable to open module file "ReplacementCostEJB.jar" in EAR file "C:\Users\Desktop\Accurev\Workspace\out\artifacts\ReplacementCostEAR_ear"
>
> [5/2/16 9:41:08:196 EDT] 0000014e InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of ReplacementCostEAR_ear started.
>
> [5/2/16 9:41:08:256 EDT] 0000014e wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl initModuleFileFromEAR Ignoring ClassCastException [ org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.FileImpl incompatible with org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.ModuleFile ]
>
> [5/2/16 9:41:08:256 EDT] 0000014e wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl rollUpRoles An error occurred while processing the roles in module 
>       EJB Module        [ org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.impl.EjbModuleImpl@227a07ee ]
>       URI               [ ReplacementCostEJB.jar ]
>       Alt DD            [ null ]
>    for application C:\Users\Desktop\Accurev\Workspace\out\artifacts\ReplacementCostEAR_ear, error message=A file does not exist for module element having uri: ReplacementCostEJB.jar
>
> [5/2/16 9:41:08:274 EDT] 0000014e InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application ReplacementCostEAR_ear failed.

We have this issue on multiple projects but can't seem to find the cause of it.  I'm not sure all of the information that I need to post here, but everywhere I've looked it seems that the application.xml is at the center of it so here that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="5"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
<display-name>
ReplacementCostEAR</display-name>
<module id="Module_1432320814462">
    <web>
        <web-uri>ReplacementCostWeb.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/V5/AOReplacementCost</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
<module id="Module_1432912864056">
    <ejb>ReplacementCostEJB.jar</ejb>
</module>
</application>
```

If there's anything else that is needed to understand the problem further, please ask.  We've been working on this for a couple days now and are stumped where to go from here.

Comment: The obvious first question would be, do you have a proper deployment descriptor at META-INF/ejb-jar.xml?  META-INF should be relative to root of ejb jar and as noted the path is case sensitive.  Are both your war and ejb jars in the root of the ear?

Comment: More specifically, a JAR file must contain either a `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` file or it must contain an EJB component-defining annotation (`@Stateless`, `@Stateful`, `@MessageDriven`, or `@Singleton`).  What is the content of ReplacementCostEJB.jar?  Does it contain one of those items?